# Iterate and append to table

Tags: javascript, iteration

Hello i am trying to append some strings from an array to an table. I want every array item to have its own tr element.

The things i have tried so far is this:

```js
const body = document.body
const table = document.createElement('table')
const tr = document.createElement('tr')
const th = document.createElement('th')
const form = document.createElement('form')
const  label = document.createElement('label')

table.innerHTML
body.append(table)

tr.innerHTML
table.append(tr)

const thText = ["ID", "First name", "Last name", "Email", "Phone number", "Actions"]

thText.forEach((text)=>{
  th.innerHTML = text
  tr.append(th);
})
```

When `console.log(th)` i get `<th> Actions </th>` 6 times. but the only thing that is rendered is Actions once.
Would love to get some help. Thanks :)

Comment: `th` refers to one single element. Your `forEach` is repeatedly modifying the text of, and re-appending, the same element over and over. Consider something like [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Comment: or move `.createElement("th")` into the `.forEach()` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only creating one `th` element. You'd need to create one for each iteration, so, within the loop:

```
thText.forEach(text => {
  const th = document.createElement('th')
  th.innerHTML = text
  tr.append(th)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to do this.  Here's an example of one way.  This method does a few things differently then your example.

- It creates and uses a `thead` element for proper table formatting.
- It uses a basic for loop method.
- It creates a new `th` element for each header label in the array, then it appends it to the `tr` element.
- It uses `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
const headerLabels = ["ID", "First name", "Last name", "Email", "Phone number", "Actions"]
const body = document.body
const table = document.createElement('table')
const thead = document.createElement('thead')
const tr = document.createElement('tr')

thead.append(tr)
table.append(thead)
body.append(table)

for (let i = 0; i < headerLabels.length; i++)  {
    let th = document.createElement('th')
    th.textContent=headerLabels[i]
    tr.append(th)
}
```

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}
  
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
  
th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```